# How to add an id to a background image

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

I am suppose to make this tag

```
<img id="image" class='img' src="adventure.jpg" height="80%" width="70%">
```

to a background iamge, the only problem is that the background image is changed by the filters such as opacity and etc. So i need the id of the image because of the image being used in the js.

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need id of background image when you can control everything from the id of the element the background image is applied to.